# Appcode chaining methods indentation does not match with xcode indentation

Tags: swift, appcode

XCode indents method chaining like this:
[xcode method chaining indentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPMch.png)

However if I press auto-format on appcode, it formats it in a weird way:
[appcode method chaining indentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgpZz.png)

Does appcode have a configuration in the code-style to fix this? When I look into their coding style for swift, I can't seem to find the configuration to change this behavior.

Anyone know a way to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Here's the relevant feature request: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/OC-20293

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:**

Another more convenient option is to use https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7177-file-watchers

with next conf:

[image]

More in docs:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-watchers.html#showFileWatcherInfoInEditor

**PREVIOUS:**

AppCode issue is very old...

So i solved it using https://github.com/nicklockwood/SwiftFormat :

1. `brew install swiftformat`
2. Add `External Tools`
   (program: `/path/to/swiftformat`, arguments: `$FilePath$`, working directory: `$ProjectFileDir`):

[image]

[image]

3. Add `KeyMap` to your taste:

[image]